# Helmholtz energy in terms of grand partition function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

According to my source of notes 
$$A = kT \left ( N \ln z-\ln Z(z, V, T)\right) $$
where $z=e^{\beta \mu}$, $\mu$ being chemical potential, $Z(z,V,T)$ is  partition function for grand canonical ensemble. The derivation process is  as follows in the image. It simply ignores the summation and take $\log$ at particular value of $N$. Can anyone confirm it or give me link me to right relation?

[image]

Comment: 1. Please do not post pictures of formulae, but type them out in MathJax. 2. This indeed seems like a blatant error in those notes.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  I am sorry but could you give me link or any book which gives the correct relation to it?